# C# Sniffing https traffic from a 3rd party assembly with fiddler

Tags: .net, https, fiddler

I want to sniff https traffic with fiddler, but the traffic is generated via a 3rd party assembly instead of a web browser.
Are there similar mechanisms available so that I can add the fiddler certificate into the trusted category or would you recommend any other trick?

Comment: Does adding the Fiddler certificate to the trusted certificate store as here http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp not work?

Comment: Maybe the question is then if a .NET web application uses this setting or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default, .NET relies on the Windows Trusted Root store, so you can follow the steps specified at the link Martin provided: fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

Alternatively, after Fiddler's root certificate is created, you can run the following from an Admin command line:

```
certmgr /add /c /s my /n DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot /s root
```

Comment: I had DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot in the trusted root store, while accessing the https site, the site now rejects all my request.  HttpAnalyzer works well though

Comment: I don't know what "rejects all my request" means, but given that there are thousands of people who do this with Fiddler every day, I suspect there's something unique about your setup.